# Mac OS X users with empty name

Tags: macos, user-account

Looking at my Users & Groups I have just noticed two users I never payed any attention before. 
Maybe they already exist from the beginning of time i.e. when my macbook pro was installed for the first time.
But, as told, I have never, ever, ever noticed them.

Does anyone know where these users come from and if I can delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No clue where they come from, is your macbook refurbished by any chance?

Just remove them if you don't use them.

They have no username, so they kinda don't have any folder related.

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer, is there any chance they come from any kind of hack or malware?

Comment: Looks like it tried to create an account buy couldn't complete it somehow - because there's no username set and it's mandatory.

Comment: ah, interesting. May be because I have installed few db servers (mysql or mongodb for example). May be the installation have created an administration user. Is there any chance to know their user_id ?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe someone else does?